# Applying sorting function to all grouped data in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For example, I have a data frame as so:

```
A B
1 1
1 1
4 0
5 1
6 1
7 0
1 1
4 0
5 0
6 1
4 0
```

and I would like to keep all 'groups' in A (so all 1s, all 2s, all 3, etc, or if string, all identical strings), which have say 1 in B (or contain a single value which is say greater or equal to something.)

so the output here would be

```
A B
1 1
1 1
5 1
6 1
1 1
5 0
6 1
```

The way I imagine in it in my head is:

df[ (df['A'] == *groupedAsSameThing?* ) & (df['B'] >=0.5)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
df[df.A.isin(df.loc[df.B>0,'A'])]
```

This is a literal approach to what you need: df for which df[A] is in the df[A] column when you filter out all rows where df[B]>0

```
Out[10]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
3  5  1
4  6  1
6  1  1
8  5  0
9  6  1
```

Comment: Nice, this covers both the string and float situation, and I don't have to use 'groupby'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is `groupby().transform()`:

```
df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max') >= 0.5]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
3  5  1
4  6  1
6  1  1
8  5  0
9  6  1
```

Comment: what does IIUC mean?

Comment: @ArcoBast [If I Understand Correctly](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=IIUC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to use transform('max')?
This wouldn't cover my case where 'if it's a string'.

Comment: Transform max is applied on `B`, not on `A`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I could be trying to group together two strings. Looks like one of the comments answers of transform ('any') covers it though.

Comment: transform max and transform any do the same thing in this situation. I’m not so sure what you mean atm.

Comment: I just can't use that code if both are a string. Generically of course.
I'd have to replace the 'max' with 'any' else it throws an error.

Comment: I see your point, so `B` column also contains string? Unusual use case, but if `any` works for you then `any` it is :-). Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There's GroupBy.filter exactly for this.

```
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).filter(lambda g: (g['B'] > 0).any())
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('any')]`

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying to figure out how to use groupby properly. This works just as well. Both for the case of strings, and floats.